# regular expression for [STRING] in gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: regex, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am tyring to set rule for deployment stage in gitlab-ci.yml file where if the git commit message is having a particular [STRING] in this format then it should deploy to that particular environment where this rule is written.

```
# Deploy to QAT environment
deploy-qat:
  stage: deploy
  extends: .helm_deploy
  environment:
    name: qat
  tags:
    - exe-prd
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ "/[QAT]$/|/[qat]$/"  #&&  $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "example/qat"
      when: always
```

I have wrote above rule however it is not working. I have tried below combinations of regular expressions however none of them are working.

```
"/\[QAT\]/|/\[qat\]/"
"/[QAT]/|/[qat]/"
"*\[QAT\]*|*\[qat\]*"
"\[\(QAT\|qat\)\]"
"\[\(QAT\|qat\)]"
"/\[(qat|QAT)\]/"
```

I tried following website for regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/6) which validates my requirement but it is not working inside gitlab-ci.yml file.

Comment: Try `"^(QAT|qat)$"` (POSIX ERE) or  `"^\(QAT\|qat\)$"` (POSIX BRE). If the string contains `[` and `]` chars, try `"^\[(QAT|qat)]$"` or  `"^\[\(QAT\|qat\)]$"`.

Comment: It didn't work. A typical commit message would be like below.
"Testing commit message rule for [QAT] environment."

Comment: Ah, then remove `^` and `$`. These anchors require a full string match.

Comment: `"\[\(QAT\|qat\)]"` and `"\[\(QAT\|qat\)\]"` didn't work.

Comment: So, `"\[(QAT|qat)]"` works, right?

Comment: "\[(QAT|qat)]" didn't work. Only build and test stages are getting executed and not the deploy stage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229718/discussion-between-shailesh-sutar-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: I think this `if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[(QAT|qat)]/` must work. It is a valid POSIX ERE expression. Just  had a look at [`rules:variables`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#common-if-clauses-for-rules) docs.

Comment: Hey Wiktor this solutions works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use

```
# Deploy to QAT environment
deploy-qat:
  stage: deploy
  extends: .helm_deploy
  environment:
    name: qat
  tags:
    - exe-prd
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /\[(QAT|qat)]/
      when: always
```

See more about how to format regex matching conditions at the [`rules:variables`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#common-if-clauses-for-rules) reference page.

NOTES:

- `/\[(QAT|qat)]/` should not be put inside quotes
- You need to use `/.../` regex literal syntax (the backslashes are regex delimiters)
- `\[(QAT|qat)]` is a regex that matches `[`, then either `QAT` or `qat`, and then a `]` char
- `=~` is a regex matching operator.

Comment: Here is a direct link to regex compoarison to variables:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#compare-a-variable-to-a-regex-pattern

Answer (score 0):

Try this block in your yml:

```yaml
deploy-qat:
  only:
    message:
      - /\[(qat|QAT)\]/
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir but I need to check multiple conditions at the time of deployment. The branch must be example/qat and commit message must have [QAT] or [qat] tag in it for QA environment deployment else a simple commit message on the same branch would deploy to a different environment. lets say dev environment. I can't use only and rule directive at the same time.

Comment: My mistake. But have you try this pattern in your code example?

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts. I tried this pattern in my code and it is still not deploying code to QA environment.

Comment: One last thing:
  
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/
  
here I saw an example of pretty same "if" statemant but without quotes around pattern - have you try this before?

Comment: I tried the suggested solutions however the gitlab-ci.yml file becomes invalid when I use them without quotes,