# How to add regex to a label in recordingrules.yaml file

Tags: gitlab-ci, prometheus, grafana, promql

In the recordingrules.yaml I have a rule which should work for uat and test environment.
what regex should I add to my env labels so that this rule work for both of the environments.

```
groups:

- name: test:gitlab:cicd
  rules:
  -record:
   expr:
   labels:
     env: uat/qa
```

Comment: Maybe as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66545742/6309? `env:` (next line) `- /(uat|qa)/`